# Exception sending context initialized

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, log4j, jboss5.x

When i am running my application it give me this exception:-

```
Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class                  
org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

But this problem is not permanent. If i remove the log4j entries from web.xml and restart p.c and then again add log4j entries and start the server, then the application works fine.
I noticed that when the application is deployed and when i undeploy and again deploy the same application, this problem emerge.

Please help me ........ i am facing this problem from 3 months...

Answer (score 0):

I just investigated it a little and have found the similar issue:

It causes when multiple jar file for log4j is available to application.
From web/application server and from build path(Included from other
path rather than web/application server)

You can see the entire thread here:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/551933/Spring/Exception-sending-context-initialized-event

looks like this is your problem.

Comment: I know this is the reason but what should i do about it ..... as i am using jboss and there is a log4j jar in the lib of jboss and i have one log4j jar in my application but i am running mu application through myeclipse not by creating the war using ant or maven....Do u have any solution for that....